# How do I make my Data Labels in my Excel chart have a square next to it that are the same are the ones in my Legend?

Tags: excel, charts

I have a Pie chart and since there are many data I want to show values and % in the Data Labels. Those two are quite simple but I want to add the square next to the data labels that is the same as the one that appears in the Legends so it is easier to know what you are looking for.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on the data label, select "Format Data Labels..." and under "Label Options" check the "Legend Key" checkbox.

This will add the little square as it appears on the legend.